# Build flag added to the configuration and causes pipeline fail

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt, cyclomatic-complexity

I am using STM32CubeIDE which is based on eclipse.
The problem is that a flag is added and don't know how it was added it is called **-fcyclomatic-complexity**.

It causes the inclusion of .cyclo files. How can I remove this build flag? or should it be added to the pipeline?

I tried to unselect the Cyclomotic Complexity flag and it passed the pipeline. But I am not sure is that the correct solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Cyclomatic-Complexity]

Just deselect the Cyclomatic Complexity check box, it will remove the -fcyclomatic-complexity flag from the build.

Refer the section 4.1 of  https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2609-stm32cubeide-user-guide-stmicroelectronics.pdf

.cyclo files contain the result of the cyclomatic complexity analysis. Removing it won't hurt your build or your final .elf.
It is just a tool to measure your branching complexity of each of the functions you have implemented or used.